# object reference not set to an instance of an object when reading an xml file

Tags: c#, xml, list, hyperlink

I created a class named Client.
I want to read an xml file and fill a list of Clients. 
here is the code :

```
List<Client> lc = new List<Client>();

                Client c = new Client();

                c.IdClient = "";
                c.NomClient = "";
                c.PrenomClient = "";

                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(pathXml);
                XmlNodeList clients = doc.SelectNodes("//Kunde");

                foreach (XmlNode client in clients)
                {

                    //c.IdClient = (from v in XDocument.Load(pathXml).Descendants("Kunde")
                                //  select v.Element("KundNR")).FirstOrDefault().ToString();


                    c.IdClient = doc.SelectSingleNode("//KundNr").Attributes[0].InnerText.ToString();
                   c.NomClient = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Nachname").ToString();
                    c.PrenomClient = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Vorname").ToString();
                  lc.Add(c);
                }
                lc.Add(c);
                return lc;
```

But when I run shows me this exception : object reference not set to an instance of an object . Please help

Comment: This is likely the most common exception in C#. There are already way too many questions about it when they all have the same answer, you're using the `.` (access operator) on an reference which is currently null. Stop through your code inspecting the values of each of your references and you'll find out very quickly why it's happening.

Comment: the problem is in id.clients , what should I do? help please

Comment: I'm not seeing that line.. One option is to do `if (id != null)` then access `id.clients` if it is null I can't tell you what to do because I'm not sure what you would expect it to be but think about how that is allocated/initialized, what value you expect to be there, why it is null instead and how you can prevent that from happening.

Comment: Oh I see now, you mean this line `c.IdClient = doc.SelectSingleNode("//KundNr").Attributes[0].InnerText.ToString()` ok, so the thing is you are using selectsinglenode to return a reference thing you access attributes on that then on that you access inner text and then on that you call to string if any of those methods fail they return null and you get the exception. Your xpath stuff could be wrong, but you should add more checks to ensure that you actually are getting the xml piece you want rather than just trying to act on it.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing the xml but `doc.SelectSingleNode("//KundNr").Attributes[0]` looks suspect.

Comment: looks like this : 
<Kunde>
   <KundNr> test1 </KundNr>
   <Nachname> aaaa </Nachname>
</Kunde>
Yes the error in that line